# Ajax request and copy some rows with php pdo but change some values

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

I have this database:

[image]

and I have this ajax request:

```
$("#noviDatum").click(function() {
    var nd = $('#nD').val();
    $.ajax({
            url: "addDate.php",
            type: "POST",
            async: true, 
            data: {ajdi:ajdi,nd:nd}, //your form data to post goes here as a json object
            dataType: "html",

            success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);   
            },  
        });


});
```

so ajdi = id_akt

Now I want to when I run `addDate.php` to copy all rows `where id_akt = ajdi and where prvi = 1` but then I need to change `datum` to coped rows with `nd` value (which is also date) and `vrednost to 0`.

Is it possible to do that and How? Also how save is this method? What you suggest?

**UPDATE:
I try this with php pdo, but something is wrong:**

```
try {
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      $rez = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM track_aktivnosti WHERE id_akt = :id_akt AND prvi=1");
      $rez->execute(array(':id_akt' => $_POST['id_akt']));
      $kol = $rez->fetchAll();


foreach ($kol as $r) {
    $STH = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO track_aktivnosti (datum, prvi, id_akt, tabela, id_tabele, naziv, vrednost) VALUES ($r['datum'], 0, :id_akt, $r['tabela'], $r['naziv'], 0)");
          $STH->execute(array(':id_akt' => $_POST['id_akt']));


$STH->execute();
}


    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: also values on new rows on column prvi need to be 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first things off, I'm assuming that your addDate.php already has the basic logic implemented for communicating with a mysql database and that you are a good coder and checking all vales passed by the ajax post for any evil input.

You would then basically first need to retrieved the rows you want to copy and modify:

```
...
$ajdi = $_POST['ajdi'];
$nd = $_POST['nd'];
...

$select_rows = query("SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE `id_akt`= $ajdi AND `id_akt`= 1") or die(mysql_error());

while($data = fetch_assoc($select_rows))
{
    //we'll handle this in the next section
}
...
```

After you have retrieved your rows, you will need to change each rows data accordingly and then insert it back into the table.

```
...
while($data = fetch_assoc($select_rows))
{
     $insert_row = query("INSERT INTO your_table (datum, prvi, other cols..) VALUES ($nd, $data['prvi'], other values...)");

     if ($insert_row) {
         /// Delete old row if needed by using $data['id']
     }
}
...
```

Let me know if you need any other information.

**UPDATE:** 
I've made some changes to your updated code and added a few error echos to see if something is going wrong, but for further clarification where the error is, you will definitely need to debug your code:

```
try {
      // Check if value is set
      $id_akt = $_POST['id_akt'];
      echo "Passed id: " . $id_akt . "\r\n";

      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=" . $dbname, $username, $password);
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      $rez = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM track_aktivnosti WHERE id_akt = :id AND prvi=1");
      $rez->bindValue(':id', $id_akt, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $rez->execute();
      //$data = $rez->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      while($r = $rez->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

          // Check if we are in loop
          echo "Processing row data:";
          print_r($r);
          echo "\r\n";

          $STH = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO track_aktivnosti (datum, prvi, id_akt, tabela, id_tabele, naziv, vrednost) VALUES (:r_datum, 0, :id_akt, :r_tabela, 0, :r_naziv, 0)");

          $STH->execute(array(':r_datum' => $r['datum'],':id_akt' => $id_akt, ':r_tabela' => $r['tabela'], ':r_naziv' => $r['naziv'] ));

          $affected_rows = $STH->rowCount();

          echo "Affected rows: " . $affected_rows;
          echo "\r\n";
          echo "\r\n";
     }


} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Clearly you have a few problems in your version:

- The Select call is prepared but never executed as far as I can see.
- On the insert command, if you prepare a query, you should pass all variables on execute (or bind them before)
- Your second query was missing the value for *id_table*
- You were double executing the insert command.

Most problems can often be resolved by taking your time and thinking about what you just wrote and double checking it for logical errors.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please be aware, the code is not complete. You will need to insert your own values and complete the query as needed.

Comment: _Note:_ You should stear clear of **`mysql_*`** functions as it is depreciated. Look into [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/mysqli)

Comment: how this will looks like in php PDO ?

Comment: I UPDATE MY QUESTIOn WITH PHP PDO CODE but soemthing is wrong with that

Comment: Now after chech error i get this: Passed id: 25
Processing row data:Array
(
    [ID] => 192
    [datum] => 2013-04-01
    [prvi] => 1
    [id_akt] => 25
    [tabela] => zalihe
    [id_tabele] => 1
    [naziv] => gorivo biodizel
    [vrednost] => 0
)

ERROR: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2013-04-01-25-zalihe-1-gorivo biodizel' for key 'track_aktivnosti_5cols'

Comment: SO MY INSERT QUERY DONT WORK WELL BECOUSE RETURN SAME VALUES< DONT CHANGE ALUES WITH MY VALUES ...